# iPhone project "No launchable executable present at path"

Tags: iphone, ios

I downloaded one of the sample apps for iOS and it gives me the above error. 
No launchable executable present at path /Users/..../MyProject/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app

What i do have is the MyProject/build/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GeneratedResources.build/ some files.

No build errors.

When I see in the finder the directory is indeed not even present. What could be the problem ?

Update: Yes, i did try cleaning & deleting Build directory, doesn't help

Comment: try clean and rebuild...

Comment: done that several times.

Comment: also try removing the app from the device and restarting xcode. Sometimes I've gone so far as to restart a device. XCode Voodoo.

Comment: Using simulator, restarted that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this same error code for my project. I was using a number in the Target -> Product Name.  Once I changed the Product Name of the target to **letters only** everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Info.plist and removing "executable name" value if it's filled with custom string instead of string variable (the one that should look like `${FOO_BAR}`, but doesn't).

Comment: "executable file" has value "${EXECUTABLE_NAME} I guess thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  it turned out I had the active target set incorrectly, in my case to a cocos library instead of to my own app.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the things mentioned here, also make sure you click on "Clean All Targets" then quit XCode and restart XCode. This fixed it for me and many others on the web!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I had an additional target for the same project (which contained test libraries). At some point xCode always tried to launch the test binary, regardless of what binary it compiled.

Removing the pbxuser and perspective files (inside project.xcodeproj) solved it for me.